# Print the json data passed from node JS to EJS in string format rather than JSON sytax

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ejs

This is my document schema:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b96cf0137127b27c5cd7fb"),
    "theatreid" : 10,
    "name" : "inox raghuleela ",
    "location" : "vashi",
    "address" : "sec 2,vashi, Mumbai, Maharashtra 410234",
    "shows" : [
            {
                    "mname" : "shubh mangal savdhan",
                    "timings" : [
                            6,
                            7,
                            9,
                            11,
                            15,
                            18
                    ]
            },
            {
                    "mname" : "Toilet:ek prem katha",
                    "timings" : [
                            11,
                            12,
                            13,
                            14,
                            15
                    ]
            }
    ]
}
```

I am using nodejs ,and passing the values of the retrieved query(displaying the timing array where value is greater than 10) to EJS. This works fine!
The output  is as follows:[EJS output in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAbif.png)

My index.ejs is as follows:

```
<header>
    <% include ../partials/header %>
</header>

<main>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>This is great</h1>
        <p>Welcome to templating using EJS</p>

        <h2>Loop</h2>

   <ul>
     <% result.forEach(function(r) { %>
      <li><%= r.name %> <%- JSON.stringify(r.shows)%></li>
       <% }); %>
        </ul>
```

But, i dont want to display the output in JSON format,I want the timings to displayed in normal string formatted way.
     What needs to be done.
 Please help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSON.stringify()` used to convert a JavaScript object into a string, thus on your webpage you have output like: `[{"timings": [21]}, {"timings": [20, 21]}]`.

You need to use [Array.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) instead of `JSON.stringify()`:

```
<% result.forEach(function(r) { %>
    <li><%= r.name %></li>
    <ul>
        <% r.shows.forEach(function(s) { %>
            <li><%= s.mname %> - <%= s.timings.toString() %></li>
        <% }) %>
    </ul>
<% }) %>
```

or [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
...
<% r.shows.forEach(function(s) { %>
    <li><%= s.mname %> - <%= s.timings.join(', ') %></li>
<% }) %>
...
```

If you need only output values greater than `10` you can use `filter`:

```
<% result.forEach(function(r) { %>
    <li><%= r.name %></li>
    <ul>
        <% r.shows.forEach(function(s) { %>
            <li><%= s.mname %> - <%= s.timings.filter(function(item) { return item >= 10 }).join(', ') %></li>
        <% }) %>
    </ul>
<% }) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call .toString() on your object:

```
var j = {"a":["b","c"]}

j.a.toString() //-> "b,c"
```